# Plot a 3d plot in Python from elements in a 2D matrix

Tags: python, matrix, 3d

I would like to plot a function f(x<sub>1,</sub> x<sub>2</sub>) of two variables x<sub>1</sub> and x<sub>2</sub> in a 3D plot. The function is containted in a 2D matrix, with x<sub>1</sub> forming the rows and x<sub>2</sub> the columns. How do I go about plotting this?

I have tried defining my function f as

```
x1_axis = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
x2_axis = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)

f = [fun[x1, x2] for x1 in x1_axis and x2 in x2_axis]
```

where 'fun' is my matrix storing the values. This raises the error 'ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.'

Is there any other way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 2d function matrix, by passing a mesh into a funcion.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def fun(x1, x2):
    # Define your function here
    return x1 + x2

x1_axis = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
x2_axis = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)

X1, X2 = np.meshgri

d(x1_axis, x2_axis)
F = fun(X1, X2)
```

You can than plot that using

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X1, X2, F)

plt.show()
```